# Array printing to textfile with an extra space, cant figure it out. Examples provided

Tags: python

An array is defined to a textfile and it prints out as such:

`array1 = 0 0 , 0   ,  0  #used commas to depict the extra space`

I need it to be like `array1 = 0 0 0 0`

when **array2** prints it prints how I need it to: `array2 = 0 0 0 0`

example of the messed up array and the working array:

```py
rssReference = self.ui.rss_reference_textbox.text()
rssEngine_1 = self.ui.rss_engine1_textbox.text()
rssEngine_2 = self.ui.rss_engine2_textbox.text()
rssEngine_3 = self.ui.rss_engine3_textbox.text()

combusterReference = self.ui.numComb_reference_textbox.text()
combusterEngine_1 = self.ui.numComb_engine1_textbox.text()
combusterEngine_2 = self.ui.numComb_engine2_textbox.text()
combusterEngine_3 = self.ui.numComb_engine3_textbox.text()

#**array **1#
postProcess_RSS = (rssReference, rssEngine_1, rssEngine_2, rssEngine_3)
rss = " ".join(postProcess_RSS)

#**array2**#
postProcess_Combustor = (combusterReference, combusterEngine_1, combusterEngine_2, combusterEngine_3)
combustor = " ".join(postProcess_Combustor)

with open(outputDir + '.txt', "w") as text_file:
    print(f'#', "\n"f'array1 = {rss}', "\n"f'array2 = {combustor}', file=text_file)

# using str() method to convert to string still returning not desired ouput
```

Comment: 1. That's not an "error"; 2. Without knowing the contents of those variables, we cannot certainly help you, so please provide a valid [mre]; 3. please don't use unrelated tags, as your post has absolutely nothing to do with PyQt nor PySide.

Comment: updated for you.

Comment: As already stated, without knowing the contents of those variables, we cannot help you, and right now we only know that you take those contents from an UI, which really doesn't clarify anything. Please read more carefully the link in my comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely that you have **extra spaces** in your variables.

```
rssReference, rssEngine_1, rssEngine_2, rssEngine_3
```

If you cannot remove the spaces from those variables ahead of time, you can remove the extra spaces from `rss` afterwards with a **regex substitution**:

```
rss = re.sub('\s+', ' ', rss)
```

Here is what your code would look like:

#### Code:

```
import re

#**array **1#
postProcess_RSS = (rssReference, rssEngine_1, rssEngine_2, rssEngine_3)
rss = " ".join(postProcess_RSS)

rss = re.sub('\s+', ' ', rss)

...
```